# Populating a Collection or Map from multiple methods in a class using a thread safe approach

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-batch, java.util.concurrent

Please advise the best approach to tackle the following:

I have a java class as follows:

```
@Service
public class ServiceAImpl {

    private final Set<String> someSet = new HashSet<>();
    private final List<Record> someList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Map<String, String> someMap = new HashMap<>();

   //Loads XML as a document
   public Optional<Document> readXML(Document xmlDoc){

   }

   //reads the root node and triggers the recursive extraction of the XML data
   public List<Record> extractRootNodeAndTriggersRecursive(){
       extractXMLRecursively(elt);

   }

   //recursively read hierarchical data in the XML
   public SomeObject extractXMLRecursively(Element elt){

   }

   public SomeObject createReportFromTheMapOrList(){

   }

}
```

I know that instance members (or list/maps) are not threadsafe.

Please what is the best way to implement a logic where a list/set/map needs to be updated or populated by multiple calls to multiple methods defined within the same class.

So, in another calling class (Main Springboot Application), I will be getting the list/set/map to process them after being populated.

I think the above code may work for a standalone application run once a week as a schedule i.e. concurrency would not be an issue. But, how should I rework it, if the service is exposed to multiple threads?

Has anyone come across this scenario?

Any ideas or tips or references will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use thread safe collections and maps, i.e. `CopyOnWriteArrayList` if you have few writes, or `List<Record> someList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())`. For maps, you can use `ConcurrentHashMap` and for sets, there exists `ConcurrentSkipListSet` or you might also use `Map<String, String> someMap = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>())`

Comment: thanks fps. How does this compare to the use of ReentrantLock as per the answer suggested by nahaev?

Comment: Locks allow to synchronize access to several collections at a time, i.e. add elements to the three collections and perform that operation atomically

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ReentrantLock`:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

@Service
public class ServiceAImpl {

    private final Set<String> setNoDuplicateLabelsAllowed = new HashSet<>();
    private final Set<String> someSet = new HashSet<>();

    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

   //Loads XML as a document
   public Optional<Document> readXML(Document xmlDoc){
       lock.lock();
       try {
           // modify your collections safely here
       } finally {
           lock.unlock();
       }
   }

   //reads the root node and triggers the recursive extraction of the XML data
   public List<Record> extractRootNodeAndTriggersRecursive(){
       lock.lock();
       try {
           // modify your collections safely here
       } finally {
           lock.unlock();
       }
   }

   //recursively read hierarchical data in the XML
   public SomeObject extractXMLRecursively(Element elt){
       lock.lock();
       try {
           // same here, etc.
       } finally {
           lock.unlock();
       }
   }
```

Note, that you need to use the same lock in every method. This guarantees that only one thread can change you collections in the particular moment of time. All other threads will be blocked unless the lock is released, no matter in what particular method they try to acquire this lock.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Nehaev. But, how do I apply the lock to multiple list/map called in different methods? Do, I need to lock and unlock all methods that have any shared resource i.e.map/list/set?

Comment: I've updated the answer, I hope now it's clearer regarding the case with multiple methods.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks to a million. Meaning that when spring instantiates the service class, only one thread will be able to use it at one time. Right?What about the options suggested by fps in my original post?

Comment: CopyOnWriteArrayList, ConcurrentHashMap and etc. are much better than lock if you have only one collection as a state of your service. If you need to keep the consistent state across multiple collections (or any other objects), you have to use lock.

Comment: Hello Nehaev, I have put the logic in and needed to test etc But, I will like to know of a design pattern used to solve the concurrency issue without the use of lock, if any. My colleague was suggesting that I could use method parameter and return type i.e. pssing the relevant collection/map into any method which updates/populates it and then returning the updated collection/map. I was thinking that will be messy since there are multiple maps and list to be updates as I traverse a large XML file and validate elements within its nodes. Any ideas.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I'm following you. Maybe it worth to create another question with more context attached.

Comment: Ok Nehaev. Thanks for the answer, I will keep you in the loop. Have a nice weekend.